# Android Background Service Controlling UI Activity

Tags: android, qt, android-activity, android-service

I am new to android application development and hence have serious troubles in getting my application running successfully. I guess most of my problems can be accounted due to lack of android platform concepts and usage of PC programming concepts on android! ;)

What I intend to do is to develop a UI based android application but I have a strong requirements that the application should behave like a daemon!
When I say daemon; when the application starts, the UI should not be visible! Based on certain wakeup event, the application show be woken up so that UI is visible to the user. Similarly based on certain sleep event, the application UI should be hidden. Something similar to the alarm application on android.

The UI part was very easy for me because I used the Qt port for android and the application works like a charm. But this works like any normal application and does not include my requirement stated above. I tried looking Qt documentation and there is no provision to achieve this and in some forum, they have recommended to use android SDK methods to achieve this.

Since I am no Java expert, I read a lot about android development and managed to create an application which ,,somewhat'' satisfies the above requirement but I have few issues and I wanted to know if I have followed the right approach. So summarizing what I did below.

1. I subclassed android.app.Service and in my overriden onStartCommand, I am creating the worker thread that checks for the wakeup and sleep event. For discussion sake let's assume wakeup event is like every 60minutes and sleep event is like 5minutes after wakeup.
2. Within onStartCommand method, I am broadcasting an Intent expecting the activity that created my service to receive it (step 6 below explains why I am doing this)
3. The worker thread on satisfying a wakeup condition, starts my UI activity as follows:

   `Intent activityIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyUIActivity.class);
   activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   getApplication().startActivity(activityIntent);`
4. The worker thread on satisfying a sleep condition, requests my UI activity to finish by broadcasting an Intent expecting the UI activity to receive it.
5. The onStartCommand finally returns START_NOT_STICKY.
6. I have a main activity that registers an instance of BroadcastReceiver with an IntentFilter to receive the Intent after the service has been started from step 2 above. On receiving the Intent I call a finish() to close the UI to daemonize my service!

The above setup works fine and I can see the service going in background with proper Toast messages and the UI also shows up when the wakeup condition is satisfied and the Qt widgets are displayed on screen perfectly.
However, I have few issues in getting this setup work in a safe way. Below are the problems (not sure if they are real problems or not):

Sometimes when I launch the app, I do not see the toast message that the service is started from the onStartCommand method but the logcat displays the following message:

`W/ActivityManager(  628): Scheduling restart of crashed service org.example.myapp/.MyService in 1000ms
I/ActivityManager(  628): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.example.myapp/.MyApplicationActivity (has extras)} from pid 21764
W/ActivityManager(  628): Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.example.myapp/.MyApplicationActivity (has extras) } from null (pid=21764, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10129`

When I try to start the application manually, it works fine!

Secindly, when I try to hide the UI activity by calling finish(); I think this is when I see the following message:

`I/WindowState(  628): WIN DEATH: Window{428ef138 u0 org.example.myapp/org.example.myapp.MyApplicationActivity}
W/ActivityManager(  628): Scheduling restart of crashed service org.example.myapp/.MyService in 1000ms
W/WindowManager(  628): Force-removing child win Window{41962f40 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{428ef138 u0 org.example.myapp/org.example.myapp.MyApplicationActivity}`

After this, the service is no longer active!

Fundamentally, my question is: is this the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly confirm when sleep event occurs your device is in sleep mode i.e. screen off or is on?

If it is already sleeping then your receiver will not receive intent because it is already sleeping. You have to set nay flag in your activity that you may check when activity resume and perform an action accordingly and finish instance of activity.

You are not seeing your toast messages because life-cycle of service is not associated with that of Activity. Services kept on running in background until you stop them explicitly or system kill them.

Comment: The sleep event I gave was just an example. But I can confirm that the device is running all the time and is not in a locked state.

I must add this: I also have requirement on my UI application that whenever the UI is running, the screen should be visible all the time (should not dim the backlight or lock automatically). Hence, inside the onResume overriden method of my main UI activity, I call getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) and inside the onPause method, I call getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) so that the device does not sleep.